# Add div without disrupting the position of the other divs

Tags: html, css

I have a footer wrapper that has two divs, positioned next to eachother, with the following css

```
#Footer {
    font-size:.9em;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    max-width:100%;
    min-width:10%;
    background-color:#c0bdbb;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0px;    
} 

#FooterListLeft {
    color:#333333;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block; 
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#FooterListRight {
    color:#676767;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block; 
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

They are perfectly centered within the wrapper div. 
How can I add another div off to the right hand side that sticks about 25% inside the footer wrapper without pushing these to the left or right?

Heres my html

`

```
    <div id="FooterListLeft" > 
        <ul>
           <li>list1</li>
        </ul> 
    </div>

    <div id="FooterListRight" > 
        <ul>
            <li>list2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="FooterNew">
        new content
    </div>

</div>`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your whole "wrapper" into a new div.  Add another DIV inside the new DIV, after all of that stuff within "wrapper", with a float:right on it.  It will appear to the right of your wrapper.  Then, adjust your positions accorindgly.

Comment: Perfect. I did a #FootWrapper {
  position:relative;
 } and position:absolute for the new div

Comment: I also suggest using Inspect Element (or Firebug in FF) to work with your CSS.  It makes all those pesky adjustments so much easier.

Comment: Infact , Inspect Element does a better job till you are tinkering with html and css part.